# Google BigQuery with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, google-bigquery

I want to get the top repositories on Github to display on my Rails App. I think I'm half way through.

This is the code I'm using on Google BigQuery:

```
SELECT repository_name, repository_url, MAX(repository_forks) as total_forks, MAX(repository_watchers) as total_watchers, repository_language
FROM [publicdata:samples.github_timeline]
GROUP BY repository_url, repository_language, repository_name
ORDER BY total_watchers DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Is there any way I can get this query's results as a JSON so I can parse them in my Rails app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Ruby client library for BigQuery here:

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/client-libraries

When you run a query, your results are stored in a temporary table (which you can copy to a permanent table if you'd like to keep them for more than 24 hours). You can read the contents of this table using the tabledata.list API:

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list